# Increase integer values within a integer array

Tags: java, arrays, int, depth-first-search

I have question regarding increase the values within a one dimensional integer array.  For example an array like `[0,0,0,0]` and I want to increase the farthest right position in the array by one so `[0,0,0,1]`.

I want to keep increase this value to a set limit for example `[0,0,0,3]` and once it reaches that limit I want to increase the value of the integer to the direct left by 1 and reset the farthest right so `[0,0,1,0]` then repeat all over again to eventually get an output like this

`[0,0,1,3]` -> `[0,0,3,3]` -> `[0,1,0,0]`

Please note I did skip a few steps but every time I want to increase only by 1.

This is what I want to use for DFS. Also the size of the array can change but only when it is first created so the size maybe 20 one run and another run it could be 5 so using a bunch of for loops wouldn't work.

I am also not looking for the answer just tip in the right direction.

Comment: It looks like assigment. What did u do, can u post code

Comment: That is the thing I am unsure on how to start coding. I am trying to solve this logically before i try to start coding

Comment: last position is `array.size() - 1`. Did this help ?

Comment: Well that part I knew I am just trying to figure how to increase the middle section of the array while following a set of rules

Comment: I don't know why the size of the array would matter, there is array.length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
function IncrementOne(int array[], int maxArrayInt, int maxArrayLength) {
    int i = maxArrayLength - 1;
    bool c = false;
    do {
       int p = array[i];
       p = p + 1;
       c = p > maxArrayInt;
       if(c) 
          array[i] = 0;
       else 
          array[i] = p;
       i = i - 1;
    }
    while(c && i >= 0)
}
```

---

IncrementOne function is called (ie `IncrementOne([0,0,3,3], 4, 3)` for your example). maxArrayLength can be automatically derived if you want.

Array runs at least once in the do / while loop

In the do while loop, get right most value in array

Increment value

Check if value is greater than maxArrayInt

If it is, then set right most value to 0 and run loop once more

If it isn't, then set right most value with incremented value and exit loop

Comment: I am not sure I understand the c = p > maxArrayInt wouldnt that get an error?

Comment: @Dave int p is compared against int maxArrayInt, resulting with a boolean (true / false)

Comment: @Dave Corrected mistakes and provided explanation.

Comment: I see thank you this helps me alot and i think I have an idea on what do now. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using a variable to keep track of the index that should receive the next increment.

```
int indicesFilled = 0;

//incrementing 
arr[arr.size() - indicesFilled - 1]++;
if (arr[arr.size() - indicesFilled - 1] >= limit)
    indicesFilled++;
```

Comment: I tried that but issue I run into is that I would need to figure out how to go multiple levels for example if I have [0,3,3,3] and my limit is 3 on any value my next step should look like [1,0,0,0] and have indices filled equal to 0 then almost immediately equal to 3 and I am unsure about how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of integers, and then use the increment operator on the array element you want to update.

```
int [] myIntArray = new int[10];
int myCurrentPos = 0;
...
myIntArray[myCurrentPos] = 1;
...
if((myIntArray[myCurrentPos] +1) == myMaxValue) {
  myIntArray[myCurrentPos] = 0;
  myCurrentPos++;
  myIntArray[myCurrentPos] = 1;
    }
  else {
myIntArray[myCurrentPos]++;  }
```

You will want to expand upon the checks I’ve included, for the additional boundary of your array size, for example.

Comment: that part is easy enough the hard I am trying to figure out is how to keep track of which increment I need to increase

Answer (score 0):

What you basically want is a number system of base 4.

```
Base 4      Base 10
0000    ->    0
0001    ->    1
0002    ->    2
0003    ->    3
0010    ->    4
0011    ->    5
0012    ->    6
0013    ->    7
0020    ->    8
```

... and so on.

So, keep a counter of numbers in base 10, convert them to your base (base 4 in this case) and store that representation appropriately in your array.

Comment: no not really that was just an example the size of the array and the upper limit can change to be anything for example [0,0,0,0,4,0,3,1] that could be array I just chose 4 and 3 as they are small and easy to deal with

Comment: So do you mean to say that the upper limit on each index of the array is different?

Comment: no they have the exact same upper limit but that limit can be different each time the code runs

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hint. It's similar to other responses but might help.

```
var basify = function (ary, base) {
    return function (amt) {
        return ary.reverse().map( (v, i) => {
            for ( ; ((amt > 0) && (v + 1) % base); v++ ) {
                amt--;
            }
            return v;
        }).reverse()
    }
}

var base4Ary = basify([0,0,0,0,0], 4)
console.log('fill: ' , base4Ary(7)) //  fill: [0, 0, 1, 3, 3]
```

The expression, `basify([0,0,0,0,0], 4)(7)`, essentially, `basify(ary, base)(amount)`, takes:

- The array to fill
- The number system base
- and the amount to distribute across the cells... basically when to
  stop.